# What is wrong in Mysql select query with mysql variable concatenated with string?

Tags: mysql

I have bellow query but has problem

```
set @lang = "en";
SELECT
 COUNT(*) AS total_of_user, 
 COUNT(*) AS "total_of_user_@lang",
 src.district AS district_name,
 src.district AS "district_name_@lang"
FROM users LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    d.district_code,
    d.name_en AS district,
    p.name_en AS province_name, 
    p.`province_code` 
  FROM 
    provinces AS p LEFT JOIN districts AS d ON p.province_code =    d.province_code 
  WHERE 
    p.province_code = '01'
) AS src ON src.district_code = users.district_code     
WHERE 
   users.district_code IS NOT NULL AND  
   users.district_code <> '' AND 
   users.province_code = '01' 
GROUP BY users.district_code
```

If I remove `"` from query the never run, but above query run and result came as `district_name_@lang` but I need the column name to be as `district_name_en`.
For any help thanks.

Comment: Try concat("total_of_user_",@lang) and the same for the second one

Comment: If you want to rename columns in a query, then you need to use dynamic sql.

Comment: @Sagi that has also problem

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use dynamic SQL for this:

```
set @lang = 'en';
set @sql = '
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_of_user, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_of_user_@lang,
       src.district AS district_name,
       src.district AS district_name_@lang
FROM users LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT d.district_code, d.name_en AS district, p.name_en AS province_name, p.`province_code` 
      FROM provinces p LEFT JOIN
           districts d
           ON p.province_code = d.province_code 
      WHERE p.province_code = ''01''
     ) src
     ON src.district_code = users.district_code     
WHERE users.district_code IS NOT NULL AND  
      users.district_code <> '''' AND 
      users.province_code = ''01''
GROUP BY users.district_code';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@en', @en);

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Note:  you cannot use parameters for column names or table names in a dynamic query.

Comment: This has also problem and query not execute.